# What is the best practice for maintenance module dependencies on yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I create a yeoman generator to help myself with front end development.
The problem is, our development environment, framework, plugins are changing so fast...
I have to update dependencies in the package.json in yeoman generator's template directory.
But, usually the package.json in yeoman generator is renamed like _package.json, because of the generator, so I cannot do just `npm update`.

So, I'll ask you what is the best way to update node modules in _package.json.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, `npm update` just update dependencies to the latest version matching your `package.json` dependencies semver ranger. It won't update the file itself.

To know which dependencies are outdated, you can either use `npm outdated` or a tool like [david](https://github.com/alanshaw/david).

What I usually do with my project is to run one of these tools on a newly generated project. This might not seems ideal, but it's actually the best way to go because:

1. You ensure your generator is still working (things can break overtime if we're not careful)
2. You'll be able to test the new versions against your project and see where you need to fix your code so it work with latest release and breaking changes.

Also, npm using semver to set versions, this mean you only need to bump dependencies when a new major version is released. This tends to not happen all that often.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon

Thank you for mention that I misunderstood the behavior of npm update.

Now I do the following step to update _package.json in generator.

1. create project from the generator `yo generator-name`
2. update package.json use [npm-check-update](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates).
3. ensure everything goes ok.
4. copy package.json into _package.json in generator

But I want to do this like

1. automatically update package.json in generator
2. start new project
3. ensure everything goes ok

I'm not sure this is the best way though...